# Argument of type 'string | any[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'. React/Redux

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, ethers.js

im getting the following message on the dispatch(setAccount(_address)) on the second file:

```
Argument of type 'string | any[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
Type 'any[]' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2345)
```

this is my store reducer for setting account (string).

```
import { createSlice, PayloadAction } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const initialState = {
  value: 'disconnected',
};

export const walletConnection = createSlice({
  name: 'account',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setAccount: (state, action: PayloadAction<string>) => {
      state.value = action.payload;
    },
    disconnect: (state) => {
      state.value = 'disconnected';
    },
  },
});

export const { setAccount, disconnect } = walletConnection.actions;

export const connectedAccount = (state: { account: { value: any; }; }) => state.account.value;

export default walletConnection.reducer;
```

this is the file where im trying to dispatch to update the value. im only getting the error on the second call of dispatch(setAccount(_address))

```
import { ethers } from "ethers";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { connectedAccount, setAccount, disconnect } from '../app/currentAccount'

export const ConnectAccount = () => {
    
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const loggedAccount = useSelector(connectedAccount);

    let selectedAccount;
    let signer;

    const init = async () => {

        let provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider((window as any).ethereum);
    
        await provider.send("eth_requestAccounts", []);
        signer = provider.getSigner();
        await signer.getAddress()
            .then((address) => {
                selectedAccount = address;
                dispatch(setAccount(address));
            });
    }
    
    (window as any).ethereum.on('accountsChanged', function (_address: string | any[]) {
        if (_address.length !== 0) {
            selectedAccount = _address;
            dispatch(setAccount(_address));
            console.log(`Current account: ${selectedAccount}`);
        } else {
            dispatch(disconnect());
            console.log('disconnected');
        }
    });

  return (
    <div>
        <div>
            {loggedAccount}
        </div>
        <button className="p-1 css-button-rounded--blue .css-button-rounded--blue:hover metamask-connect" onClick={init}>Connect</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

got any ideas what it could be? thanks in advance

Comment: You are saying that _address is either a string or an array (`any[]`).  Is it ever an array?  If so, you have to check that your address is a string before dispatching.  If not, then `function (_address: string | any[]) {` is a mistake.